# why does this error message appear, cannot convert value of type 'User.Type' to closure result type 'EventLoopFuture<_>'?

Tags: swift, vapor

When I build my project these two errors come up:

> contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which
> cannot be implicitly ignored
> .flatMap { User.self }
>
> cannot convert value of type 'User.Type' to closure result type
> 'EventLoopFuture<_>'
> .flatMap { User.self }

Here  is my code:

```swift
    import Fluent
    import Vapor
    
    struct PostController: RouteCollection {
        func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
            let posts = routes.grouped("posts")
            posts.get(use: index)
            posts.post(use: create)
            posts.group(":postsID") { posts in
                posts.delete(use: delete)
            }
        }

    func index(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Post]> {
        return Post.query(on: req.db).all()
      

    }


    func create(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Post> {
        let post = try req.content.decode(Post.self)
        //return post.save(on: req.db).map { post }
        return User.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$id == post.user_id).first()
                .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
                .flatMap { User.self }
                .$posts.create(post, on: req.db)
    }
    

    func delete(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<HTTPStatus> {
        return Post.find(req.parameters.get("postsID"), on: req.db)
            .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
            .flatMap { $0.delete(on: req.db) }
            .transform(to: .ok)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the model definition of User, please? Also, can you add explanation of what you are trying to achieve int the create route.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the `flatMap` method on `EventLoopFuture`.

Try something like :

```swift
func create(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Post> {
    let post = try req.content.decode(Post.self)
    return User.query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$id == post.user_id)
        .first()
        .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
        .flatMap { user in
            return post.create(on: req.db)
        }
        .transform(to: post)
}
```

https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/async/#flatmap